# GSON fromJson deserialize dynamically generated class

Tags: java, classloader, gson

I have

```
SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader,SearchResponse.class); List<Result> results = response.results;
```

However, I need to supply a class created using classLoader

```
File path = new File (classFilesPath + File.separator + getFileNameName() );
ClassLoader LOADER = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { path.toURI().toURL() }, LOADER);
Class loadedClass = loader.loadClass(fullyQualifiedClassName);
```

How can I use the loadedClass in gson.fromJson ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the loadedClass in gson.fromJson ?

```
Object thing = new Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, loadedClass);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got to that. However, the SearchResponse has results which is a List<Result>. List<Result> results = response.results;

How do I retrieve that using loadedClass without casting the Object thing to SearchResponse.